# prevent.Default() give compile-error in Asp.Net Core 3.0.0 Preview-7

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I had a Drag and Drop solution in preview-6 that was working. After upgrade to preview-7 I get a compile error on the `@ondragover="event.preventDefault() statment`.

I have tried to put `event.preventDefault()` into a `js-function`. It gives no error messages - but the drop event is not started/fired.

This is the code from Preview-6 that was running but in Preview 7 give a *compile-error* on `event.preventDefault()`.

```
    <div class="container-fluid"
                dropzone="move"
                @ondragenter="@(e => OnContainerDragEnter(e))"
                @ondragover="event.preventDefault()"
                @ondragleave="@(e => OnContainerDragLeave(e))">

            @foreach (var felt in feltList.OrderBy(p => p.DisplayOrder))
            {
                <div draggable="true" class="bm-3" title="Felt"
                     @ondragstart="@(e => OnItemDragStart(e, felt))"
                     @ondrop="@(async (e) => await OnContainerDrop(e, felt))">

                    <div class="form-group"
                         @onclick="@((e) => SelectEditField(felt.FeltDefinitionId))">

                        <EditCard felt="@felt"
                                  fieldToEdit="@FieldToEdit"
                                  skjemaId="@SkjemaId"
                                  @OnClick="@(async () => await Delete(felt.FeltDefinitionId))">
                        </EditCard>

                        <ViewField felt="@felt"
                                   fieldToEdit="@FieldToEdit">
                        </ViewField>

                    </div>
                </div>
             }
        </div>


    @code {
        [Parameter] private string SkjemaId { get; set; }

        private string _highlightDropTargetStyle;
        private FeltDefinition itemToDropOn;
        private FeltDefinition itemToDrag;
        private FeltDefinition feltDefinition;
        protected List<FeltDefinition> feltList;
        protected Skjema skjema;
        protected int FieldToEdit;


        private void OnItemDragStart(UIDragEventArgs e, FeltDefinition dragItem)
        {
            itemToDrag = dragItem;
        }

        private void OnItemDragEnd(UIDragEventArgs e, FeltDefinition dragItem)
        {
            itemToDrag = dragItem;
        }

        private void OnContainerDragEnter(UIDragEventArgs e)
        {
            _highlightDropTargetStyle = "border:5px dashed salmon !important";
        }

        private void OnContainerDragLeave(UIDragEventArgs e)
        {
            _highlightDropTargetStyle = null;
        }

        private async Task OnContainerDrop(UIDragEventArgs e, FeltDefinition dropItem)
        {
            _highlightDropTargetStyle = null;
            itemToDropOn = dropItem;
            await ChangeDisplayNr();
        }


    }
```

This is the same code but I changed the `@ondragover="event.preventDefault()"` to a js script.

```
    <div class="container-fluid"
                dropzone="move"
                @ondragenter="@(e => OnContainerDragEnter(e))"
                @ondragover="@(async (e) => await preventDefault(e))"
                @ondragleave="@(e => OnContainerDragLeave(e))">

            @foreach (var felt in feltList.OrderBy(p => p.DisplayOrder))
            {
                <div draggable="true" class="bm-3" title="Felt"
                     @ondragstart="@(e => OnItemDragStart(e, felt))"
                     @ondrop="@(async (e) => await OnContainerDrop(e, felt))">

                    <div class="form-group"
                         @onclick="@((e) => SelectEditField(felt.FeltDefinitionId))">

                        <EditCard felt="@felt"
                                  fieldToEdit="@FieldToEdit"
                                  skjemaId="@SkjemaId"
                                  @OnClick="@(async () => await Delete(felt.FeltDefinitionId))">
                        </EditCard>

                        <ViewField felt="@felt"
                                   fieldToEdit="@FieldToEdit">
                        </ViewField>

                    </div>
                </div>
             }
        </div>


    @code {
        [Parameter] private string SkjemaId { get; set; }

        private string _highlightDropTargetStyle;
        private FeltDefinition itemToDropOn;
        private FeltDefinition itemToDrag;
        private FeltDefinition feltDefinition;
        protected List<FeltDefinition> feltList;
        protected Skjema skjema;
        protected int FieldToEdit;


        private void OnItemDragStart(UIDragEventArgs e, FeltDefinition dragItem)
        {
            itemToDrag = dragItem;
        }

        private void OnItemDragEnd(UIDragEventArgs e, FeltDefinition dragItem)
        {
            itemToDrag = dragItem;
        }

        private void OnContainerDragEnter(UIDragEventArgs e)
        {
            _highlightDropTargetStyle = "border:5px dashed salmon !important";
        }

        private void OnContainerDragLeave(UIDragEventArgs e)
        {
            _highlightDropTargetStyle = null;
        }

        private async Task OnContainerDrop(UIDragEventArgs e, FeltDefinition dropItem)
        {
            _highlightDropTargetStyle = null;
            itemToDropOn = dropItem;
            await ChangeDisplayNr();
        }

    async Task preventDefault(UIDragEventArgs e)
        {
            await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("preventDefault", e);
        }


    }
```

and the js-kode

```
    preventDefault = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    };
```

Comment: What happens if you replace `@ondragover="event.preventDefault()"` with `@ondragover="@( event => event.preventDefault())"`?

Comment: So what *is* the compilation error?

Comment: I was a little bit unclear - it's not a compile-error but a syntac error. On the statment @ondragover="event.preventDefault()" it get the syntax error : "An add or remove accessor expected"

Comment: None of the above solutions worked out. @ondragover="event.preventDefault" gave the same syntax error.  The same with @ondragover="@( event => event.preventDefault())".

Comment: The solution was to take away the @-sign from the @ondragover="event.preventDefault()" . <div class="container-fluid"
     dropzone="move"
     @ondragenter="@(e => OnContainerDragEnter(e))"
     ondragover="event.preventDefault()"
     @ondragleave="@(e => OnContainerDragLeave(e))">